# distutils ignores selected python environment

Tags: python, anaconda, distutils, python-venv

```
(py35) dims@calculon:~/Design/RAD/poseutils-python$ which python
/opt/anaconda3/envs/py35/bin/python

(py35) dims@calculon:~/Design/RAD/poseutils-python$ python --version
Python 3.5.4 :: Anaconda, Inc.

(py35) dims@calculon:~/Design/RAD/poseutils-python$ sudo python setup.py install
running install
running build
running build_py
creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/poseutils/tests
...
creating /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/poseutils
copying build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/poseutils/vizualisation.py -> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/poseutils
copying build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/poseutils/linalg.py -> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/poseutils
copying build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/poseutils/util.py -> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/poseutils
...
byte-compiling /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/poseutils/vizualisation.py to vizualisation.pyc
byte-compiling /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/poseutils/linalg.py to linalg.pyc
...
running install_egg_info
Writing /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Poseutils-1.0dev.egg-info
```

As you see, athough environment py35 is selected, which is indicated by both command line prompt and other commands, setup is still copying files to `python2.7` location.

Why? And how to fix?

**UPDATE**

Also I can import the package:

```
(py35) dims@calculon:~/Design/RAD$ python
Python 3.5.4 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Oct 13 2017, 11:22:58)
[GCC 7.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import poseutils
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'poseutils'
```

Comment: What is the OS?  maybe you could try `sudo python --version' to see if the version is python3.5.  actually, I think you could run command without sudo in your virtual environment.

Comment: @FujiaoLiu you were right: python under `sudo` was different.

Comment: @Dims this happens on all *nix platforms that use sudo - the value of many (all?) environment variables (including the PATH) is different for the root (sudo) user than your user. Thus, there is a different python found for the sudo user. I would suggest using the full path to the environment's python to be sure you're using the right one.

Comment: @darthbith sure I understand this, just didn't recognize the situation since I didn't knew how should it work normally